# add a required field to checkout/register in opencart

Tags: opencart

Opencart 1.5.5.1

I added a new field to may checkout register page:

-added to catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/register.tpl:

```
  <span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_cnp; ?><br />
  <input type="text" name="cnp" value="" class="large-field" />
  <br />
  <br />
```

and to catalog/controller/checkout/register.php:

```
$this->data['entry_cnp'] = $this->language->get('entry_cnp');
```

and

```
if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['cnp']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['cnp']) > 32)) {
                $json['error']['cnp'] = $this->language->get('error_cnp');
            }
```

If I register on checkout it works great, my problem is when I do not complete this field: I'm not aloud to proceed further but I do not get an error message like on the other requested fields

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First add 'error_cnp' variable in language file if you had not added it yet like this

```
$_['error_cnp'] = 'some error text';
```

Second, in **catalog/view/theme/default/template/checkout/checkout.tpl**:

find

```
$('#button-register').live('click', function() {
 $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/register/validate',
        // some code
        success: function() {
```

and inside this success function paste following lines

```
if (json['error']['cnp']) {
    $('#payment-address input[name=\'cnp\'] + br').after('<span class="error">' + json['error']['cnp'] + '</span>');
}
```

in between the similar looking lines (inside the `else if (json['error']) {` )

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea it was in checkout.tpl